# Где хранить дату синхронизации?

Tags: база-данных, синхронизация, кэширование

Подскажите пожалуйста новичку.
Есть задача когда необходимо загрузить, к примеру список постов пользователя, закешировать в локальную БД и через какое - время запросить измененные данные указав дату последней синхронизации. Вопрос как лучше поступить в этом случае? создать поле даты синхронизации в бд для каждой записи поста? таблицу? или хранить дату где то отдельно от бд?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Храните ее в БД. Как -- зависит от степени гранулярности синхронизации. Если в общем -- храните рядом с теми данными, которые являются единицей синхронизации. Например, если вы синхронизируете по одному посту, храните это как часть записи о посте. Если синхронизируете сразу все посты юзера -- положите к юзеру или в отдельную таблицу, которая будет ссылаться на юзера. Если синхронизируете сразу все посты -- храните в отдельной таблице (если синхронизируемых сущностей много, можете создать общую таблицу на всех).